# php json_encode does not return anything

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im trying to get json_objects from arrays. I get the array that i want to convert but json_encode does not returns anything.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$i = 1;
$country = array();
$countries = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['idPais']." ";
        echo $row['nombre']."<br>";

        $country = array(
                'idPais' => $row['idPais'],
                'nombre' => $row['nombre']
        );
        array_push($countries, $country);
    }
    print_r($countries);

    echo json_encode($countries,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }else{
    echo "false";
}
```

print_r($countries) returns this Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [idPais] => 7 [nombre] => Espa�a ) 
        [1] => Array ( [idPais] => 8 [nombre] => Francia ) 
        [2] => Array ( [idPais] => 9 [nombre] => Portugal ) 
)
```

Comment: You could either tell the Spanish people not to write their language as `español` or you could connect with UFT-8 to your database.

Comment: If I apply `json_encode` to the array directly, it works to me. I have PHP7.

Comment: Might help: [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: I have php7 too. I will try without ñ.

Comment: I tried **with** the ñ (I'm costarrican) and it worked fine.

Comment: json_encode can return string or bool. Try var_dump(json_encode(...

Comment: I solved it doing my connection with database as utf-8. Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i used 'ñ' caracter. For use it with database, i had to put this line in my code:

> mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

Thanks for all.